# How to overwrite the object representation of the index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Enums as key in pandas. Below is a small example of a dataframe which will be converted to json.

[IN]

```
# coding=utf-8
# Written in python 3.7
# pandas==0.23.4
from enum import unique, Enum

import pandas as pd

@unique
class DEMO(Enum):
    FIRST = "hello"
    SECOND = "world"


df = pd.DataFrame()
df[DEMO.FIRST] = pd.Series([1,2])
df[DEMO.SECOND] = pd.Series([1,2])
print(df.to_json())
```

[OUT]

```
{"{"name":"FIRST"}":{"0":1,"1":2},"{"name":"SECOND"}":{"0":1,"1":2}}
```

What I would like to have is that the Enum is not represented as an object defined via the function `__dir__(self)`, but instead as string containing the value equivalent to string constants:

[OUT]

```
{"hello":{"0":1,"1":2},"world":{"0":1,"1":2}}
```

Is this possible without using `DEMO.FIRST.value` or `DEMO.SECOND.value` as indices?

Comment: What is "the function `__dict__(self)`"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant __dir__, but thinking of dicts let me wrote the wrong word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the value attribute of the Enums. Then one possibility would be using a lambda with `df.rename`.

```
df.rename(lambda x: x.value, axis=1, copy=False).to_json()
# Out '{"hello":{"0":1,"1":2},"world":{"0":1,"1":2}}'
```

Answer (score -1):

I found another sollution which works pretty fine even if the enum iss more complex or consists of multiple datatypes.

```
# coding=utf-8
# Written in python 3.7
# pandas==0.23.4
from enum import unique, Enum

import pandas as pd


class Complex:
    name: str
    type: str

    def __init__(self, name: str, type: str):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


@unique
class DEMO(str, Enum):
    FIRST = Complex("Hello", "Siebzig")
    SECOND = Complex("World", "Zehn")


df = pd.DataFrame()
df[DEMO.FIRST] = pd.Series([1, 2])
df[DEMO.SECOND] = pd.Series([1, 2])
print(df.to_json())
```

will produce the output

```
{"Hello":{"0":1,"1":2},"World":{"0":1,"1":2}}
```

The important change was that I added `str` as super before `Enum`.
This is even pretty simple to use with dynamic typed ENUM contents, as long as these have a string representation (`def __str__(self) -> str:`). The Enum class will automatically check the string serialization of all the members to check if those are unique whithout the need to overwrite `__hash__(self)`